# React Testing Library unable to find text even though screen.debug() shows the text to exist

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

In a nutshell, if I grab a portion of the screen by it's label:

```
const foo = screen.getByLabelText('Some Label');
```

I can see that the element I'm interested in exists in the output:

```
debug(foo);
...
<div
  class=" css-15zcpdi-NoOptionsMessage"
>
   Something went wrong
</div>
```

However if I search for "Something went wrong" in the screen:

```
screen.getByText('Something went wrong');
```

RTL claims it can't find it:

```
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: Something went wrong. ...
```

I must be doing something wrong here.. What?

Comment: Is there any async rendering in your component ?
Can you post test code ?

Comment: Did you figure out what went wrong? I'm having a similar problem

Comment: Do you have a true [mcve] for folks to look at? (And don't underestimate the power of an MCVE: it forces _your_ to reduce your code to the bare minimum, so you almost always find the problem yourself just by trying to form one). And if you do: did you file an issue with Jest over on https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues? Because if you can cleanly reproduce this, that's almost certainly something the Jest team will want to know about.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using exact string values does not seem to work very consistently. Try a regular expression instead:

```
screen.getByText(/Something went wrong/);
```